# modelling surface coverage of spheres with spheres of varying size distribution

Tags: modeling

Suppose you have spheres (e.g. cells). You add particles to the suspended cells which are smaller but do have a size distribution rather than a single diameter. The particles stick to the cells. I would like to model how much of the cell surface is covered by particles and how much of the covered fraction is covered by which particle size fraction. I have no idea how to start (probably with a pen and a paper).

Are there any computer packages which can do similar calculations. Is there any Literature I havent found because I do not know what terms to look for? How would you approach such a task ?